# Disable/Enable a button inside a panel on an ascx control in a vb.net website from codebehind not JQuery

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, panel, updatepanel

In my website I have a vb.net ascx control which contains a number of textboxes and a button. When the button is clicked I want to disable it, then perform some actions using the values of the textboxes, and then enable the button again. The problem i'm having is that i cannot disable the button.

The ascx control contains an asp:Panel, and inside that is an asp:UpdatePanel which contains the textboxes and the button. Could the asp:Panel or the asp:UpdatePanel be preventing the button being disabled? I can empty the textboxes without a problem, but nothing seems to work on the button.

I've tried

```
btnButton.Enabled = False
```

and

```
btnButton.Attributes.Add("disabled")
```

but they have no effect. Neither does setting the Visible property to false. The UpdateMode on the Asp:UpdatePanel is set to Always. I'm not too familiar with Asp:Panels or Asp:UpdatePanels so i'm guessing it's something to do with them. Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: ok, so i've done some more testing and it seems doing btnButton.Enabled = False DOES work, so long as you do nothing else in the button click event. Why would you ever do that though? I need to able to run some code and then enable the button again. Surely this must be possible somehow?

Comment: You misunderstand how this works. When you click a button, a new HTTP request is sent to the server. This forces a full page lifecycle run for the page, including Page_Load, even for simple button clicks. This is when your code-behind runs. While the code behind is running, there is NOTHING connected to the button in the browser. It could be hundreds of miles away. When _ALL_ of the code behind is finished the final html results are sent to the client, which now has _an entirely new page_. Everything that was on the screen before is thrown away, and the new result is rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

After some more research I came across the solution. I just needed to add some attributes to my button like this:

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

This will disable the button when it is clicked, but still allows the codebehind to run as well. When the codebehind has completed the button will be enabled again.